# How to update a reactive form field by button click on different component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have an application where my requirement is upon a button click (present in header component) the form field in another component will get updated. But the problem is the value is getting set in the form control variable but is not reflecting in UI. This is the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j6hz6v?file=src/app/header/header.component.ts) I've created. You can see on button click in console log that the form has the value but is not rendered in UI. Below I am showing my code what I have done so far :

**Child Component**

```
// In TS
test = this.fb.group({
    sample: [""]
});

// In HTML
<form [formGroup]="test">
  <input placeholder="Sample" formControlName="sample" />
</form>
```

**Header Component**

```
// In TS
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";

constructor(private child: ChildComponent) {}

set() {
  this.child.test.patchValue({
    sample: "fetched value"
  });
  console.log(this.child.test.value);
}

// In HTML
<button (click)="set()">ABC</button>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
import { AppRouterModule } from './router/router.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRouterModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HeaderComponent, ChildComponent ],
  providers: [ ChildComponent ], // Specified child component to access through different component
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So this is my code. Can anyone tell me where the problem is lying ?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how the component interaction works in Angular. To share data among components, you could either use `EventEmitter` for related components or a singleton service for unrelated components.

Here is an illustration using a singleton service

**share.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
  public headerClickSrc = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  public headerClick$ = this.headerClickSrc.asObservable();

  constructor() {}
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ShareService } from "../share.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html"
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private share: ShareService) {}

  set() {
    this.share.headerClickSrc.next("fetched value");
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private share: ShareService) {}

  test = this.fb.group({
    sample: [""]
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.share.headerClick$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.closed$)
    ).subscribe({
      next: value => {
        this.test.patchValue({
          sample: value
        });
        console.log(this.test.value);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next(); // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-46yjgt?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

Comment: This one is throwing 1 bug. If the ```set()``` method is triggered once from the ```header.component.ts``` the ```ngOnInit``` in child is working fine. But after this if I route to any other component and come back again here the ```value``` in ```subscribe``` inside ```ngOnInit``` stays true. Any way to fix this ? The ```ngOnDestroy``` is used still no change