# passe data from component to another using input & output

Tags: angular, typescript

i tried pass data to msg component to filter component and the both component are injected in main component, I have tried several combinations but I still can't do it.

I don't know what to use @input or @output?

**main.component.html**

```
<app-msg></app-msg> // pass data from this component to fitler component
<app-filter (filterMSg)='msg'></app-filter>
```

**filter.component.ts**

```
filterMSg:string = '';
```

**msg.component.ts**

```
msg:string = 'text from msg component';
```

Comment: `@Input` and `@Output` are for related components where one selector is used in another. For eg. in your case you could use it for data sharing b/n Main component and either of the Msg or Filter component. For unrelated components, you could look into singleton services. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64620546/6513921).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right you want to pass a message from your msg component to your filter component ?

If it is the case you need to :

1. **Get the data from your msg component** in your main component via an @Output().
2. **Send the data received in the main component to your filter component** through an @Input().

### Step 1

In your msg.component.ts :

```
export class MsgComponent {
  @Output() messageEmitter: EventListener<string> = new EventListener<string>();

  public emitMessage(message: string): void {
    messageEmitter.emit(message);
  }
}
```

Here you create an **EventListener** that you will trigger with the method **emitMessage()** when you want it to be passed to main.

In your main.component.ts :

```
export MainComponent {
  public message: string = '';

  public getMessage(message: string): void {
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

You create a method in your main to **get the value of the @Output()**.

In your main.component.html :

```
  <app-msg (messageEmitter)=getMessage($event)></app-msg>
```

You use the method defined in your main.component.ts to get the message when the @Output() is triggered in the child.

### Step 2

In filter.component.ts :

```
export class FilterComponent {
  @Input() message: string;
}
```

You create **an @Input() that will get the data sent by the parent** (the main component).

In main.component.html :

```
<app-filter [message]=message></app-filter>
```

You **send the message from main component** (written after the '=' sign) to the child  attribute message (between brackets).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what your requirements are.

A simple example for a child component which sends data to his parent may be:

```
export class ItemOutputComponent {

  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(value: string) {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

And this is a easy example for a component which gets data from his parent.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; // First, import Input
export class ItemDetailComponent {
  @Input() item = ''; // decorate the property with @Input()
}
```

Please have a look at angular's docs for [inputs-outputs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sharing-data-between-child-and-parent-directives-and-components) too!